# How to get TextView from another Activity without coming from or going to that Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

I have a TextView in Activity A and that is where the user spends most of the time on the app. My app uses Shared Preferences to save a TextView in Activity C.
How do I get the TextView from Activity C without going to activity C when I load Activity A and/or B.
I know I can get the TextView from Activity C with intent but I think that only works if I'm coming from Activity C which I am not.

Activity A currently get's the TextView this way

```
Intent id = getIntent();
if (id.getCharSequenceExtra("idid") != null) {
final TextView setmsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.loginid2);
setmsg.setText(id.getCharSequenceExtra("idid"));
```

}

But this only works if another Activity used putExtra to get it there.

Comment: you can use startactivity for result but you will have use intent.putExtra(...);

Comment: Little strange behavior you are asking for. Why do you want to pass View between activities? If you need the values of the `TextView` only like the text, then pass the text only. Do you want to present the `TextView` in activity A? If so, then insure to have this `TextView` in `setContentView()` of activity A, if not, then just pass the values.

Comment: I need the value of TextView in Activity C to show in Activity A  without the user going to activity C.

Comment: An activity is only usefull for interaction with the user, you can get the textview's text from shared prefs in onCreate. There is no reason to pass data to a not active activity, if not impossible.

Comment: Activity C has a variable EditText apptoken. It's saves using shared Preferences. Activity A uses the apptoken. I don't want the user to have to go to Activity C just to use the apptoken.

Comment: Then just get it from the SharedPreferences after it's been saved. You don't need a View reference to do that.

Comment: How to get TextView from another activity using Shared Preferences. That will be my next question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question, what I understood is,

Whenever I load Activity A / B , its Text will show the value from Activity C. Isn't it?

Of course we can use SharedPreference. try this:

inside Activity C  ->

```
textview.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ActivityC.this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("idid", ""+s);
    editor.commit();

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

And now, inside Activity A onCreate ->

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ActivityA.this);
setmsg.setText(pref.getString("idid", "null"));
```

Thats it.

Comment: TextWatcher, SharedPreferences. I'm noticing half my questions on this site are related to both. Thank You for understanding my question even though I didn't do such a good job of explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't save a `View` instance with `Sharedpreferences`. Only primitive types can be saved in `SharedPreferences`. See the [`SharedPreferences.Editor's`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) put methods.

To pass your`TextView's` `String` value from one `Activity` to another, either

- save it in Activity A using `editor.putString(...)` and retrieve it in Activity B, or
- pass it between the Activities in an `Intent`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get the TextView but a String preference:

```
public static void setLangName(Context context, String name) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(
            FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(KEY_LANG_NAME, name);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getLangName(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getString(KEY_LANG_NAME, null);
}
```

In your activity's layout you put a TextView and setText with the preference value