# setText() from not layout xml

Tags: java, android, xml

is it possible to do a `setText()` from one class to another, let me explain, for example `class A` have the layout `A.xml` and `class B` have `B.xml`.

**Is possible to `setText()` to a TextView in B.xml from class A?**

I tryed doing this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_match_finder);
hold = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hold);
hold.setText("");
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: You will find a much better answer on a question I asked a couple of years ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006864/how-to-get-textview-from-another-activity-without-coming-from-or-going-to-that-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send text via intent from one class to another and then set it as the textview like so:

class a:

```
 String word = "hello";

Intent send= new Intent(a.this,b.class);
                send.putExtra("TAG", word);   
                a.this.startActivity(send);
```

then in class b

```
String getVal;
        getVal = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TAG");

        textview.setText(getVal);
```

obviously the intent in class a needs to be sent using some sort of button click depending on what your design wants.